# Configuring Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for OAuth2/ OpenID Connect application on PingFederate

Tags: pingfederate

Can someone please let us know how PingFederate admin can configure "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" at PingFederate side to allow the source?

At present, when our domain is trying to invoke token URI on PingFederate, we get back CORS policy error stating No Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present error.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-111/page/ird1564002990806.html):
System → OAuth Settings → Authorization Server Settings

There's a section there for CORS settings.

If this doesn't solve the issue, then you need to update your question with more information, such as what specifically is failing.

Comment: K, can we add multiple urls in above settings?. Let me tell you scenario, 1. https:\\test.com is the origin request coming and we had configured allowed origins in ping config https://test.com, https://test1.com, https://test2.com. In this case , what will be returning in "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in response header , please answer at the moments its not returning any, so please suggest how to resolve it

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple URLs there... But those settings only cover the OAuth specific endpoints, not **all** endpoints. You say "token URI", but you're not specific about the error, the endpoint, nothing. Low effort posts get low effort answers, frankly, and even though I told you more info was needed, you still didn't provide anything helpful other than some URIs. [shrug]